# Regarding the definition of a Closed Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I found this definition:
Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces, $D$ a
subspace of $X$, and $T : D → Y$ a linear operator. The operator $T$ is closed
if its graph is closed in $X\times Y$.

What if $X$ were a subspace of a normed space, say, $V$? So $D$ is also a subspace of $V$. Then for the above definition to be valid, the graph of $T$ must also be closed in $V\times Y$. I understand that if it were closed in $V\times Y$ then it *will* be closed in $X\times Y$, being the intersection of a closed set in the bigger space with $X\times Y$. But why is it true the other way around as well?

Comment: Oh wait, is there a dependency on the space $X$ itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about closed operators we think of $X,Y,D$ as all given in advance. The converse implication here is not true unless $X \times Y$ is closed in $V \times Y$. The question of closedness of an operator not being well defined does not arise because we fix the spaces in advance.

Comment: To add more clarity to this an unbounded operator is a quadruple $(X,D,Y,T)$ where $D$ is a subspace of $X$ and $T:D \to Y$ is a linear map. If you change any of the four elemenst you are talking about a different unbounded operator. Unfortunately books rarely clarify this point.